# python-keycloak assign_client_role() error

Tags: python, keycloak

I'm using keycloak python API to assign user roles. Here is the code:

```
from keycloak import KeycloakAdmin
# make connection        
admin = KeycloakAdmin(server_url = "https://xxx.xx.xx/auth/",
                                   username = 'xx',
                                   password = 'xxx',
                                   realm_name = "xxx-xxx",
                                   verify = True)
# get an user id via user name
userID = admin.get_user_id(self.userName)
# assign user role
admin.assign_client_role(client_id = "client_id", 
                             user_id = userID, 
                             #role_id = "role_id", 
                             role_name = "test")
```

The `make connection` and `get user id via user name` part is successful. But `assign_client_role()` gives me an error:

```
TypeError: assign_client_role() got an unexpected keyword argument 'role_name'
```

It seems that the arguments are not corrsponding to those defined in the function. My code refers to the example from this [website](https://bitbucket.org/agriness/python-keycloak).
Could anyone tell me how to make it right?

Comment: # Assign client role to user. Note that BOTH role_name and role_id appear to be required.?

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem. It turns out that the documentation for python-keycloak is not correct. Here's how I managed to fix the issue

**First**, make sure you're using client_id from url not the client id from keycloak interface (see picture):

[client_id picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcP6e.png)

**Second**, make sure your admin user has `manage-users` and `manage-clients` roles assigned to it:

[roles picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awIqx.png)

**Third**, assign_client_role() accepts argument role_name as an array, not string

Here's my code:

```
keycloak_admin = KeycloakAdmin(server_url="http://localhost:8088/auth/",
                                        username='azat_admin',
                                        password='some_password',
                                        realm_name="realm_name",
                                        verify=True)

new_user = keycloak_admin.create_user({"email": "some_email",
                                       "username": "some_username",
                                       "enabled": True,
                                       "firstName": "some_firstname",
                                       "lastName": "some_lastname",
                                       "credentials": [{"value": "some_password","type": "password",}]})

roles = keycloak_admin.get_client_roles(client_id="2b50a8e3-dc91-4658-a552-83fb768badc8")
keycloak_admin.assign_client_role(client_id = "2b50a8e3-dc91-4658-a552-83fb768badc8", 
                                                user_id = new_user, 
                                                roles=[roles[0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Wang.

Another option is this:

```
from keycloak import KeycloakAdmin

# make connection            
admin = KeycloakAdmin(server_url = "https://xxx.xx.xx/auth/",
                                   username = 'xx',
                                   password = 'xxx',
                                   realm_name = "xxx-xxx",
                                   verify = True)
# get an user id via user name
user_id = admin.get_user_id("username")

role = admin.get_client_roles(client_id="client_id", role_name="test")

# assign user client role
admin.assign_client_role(client_id = "client_id", 
                         user_id = user_id, 
                         roles=[role])
```

I will fixe de documentation about that.

The new oficial repository is ["python-keycloak"](https://github.com/marcospereirampj/python-keycloak).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in example documentation. You should certainly try first:

*# Get client role id from name

role_id = keycloak_admin.get_client_role_id(client_id=client_id, role_name="test")*

then

*# Assign client role to user. Note that BOTH role_name and role_id appear to be required.

keycloak_admin.assign_client_role(client_id=client_id, user_id=user_id, role_id=role_id, role_name="test")*

Or can you share more of your code and explain why you commented the 'role_id' argument?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the documentation is wrong, I check the source code of `keycloak_admin.py` found the definition of function `assign_client_role()`:

```
def assign_client_role(self, user_id, client_id, roles):
    """
    Assign a client role to a user

    :param client_id: id of client (not client-id)
    :param user_id: id of user
    :param client_id: id of client containing role,
    :param roles: roles list or role (use RoleRepresentation)
    :return Keycloak server response
    """

    payload = roles if isinstance(roles, list) else [roles]
    params_path = {"realm-name": self.realm_name, "id": user_id, "client-id":client_id}
    data_raw = self.connection.raw_post(URL_ADMIN_USER_CLIENT_ROLES.format(**params_path),
                                    data=json.dumps(payload))
    return raise_error_from_response(data_raw, KeycloakGetError, expected_code=204)
```

The `URL_ADMIN_USER_CLIENT_ROLES` is defined in `urls_patterns.py`:

`URL_ADMIN_USER_CLIENT_ROLES = "admin/realms/{realm-name}/users/{id}/role-mappings/clients/{client-id}"`

As you can see, the `realm-name`, `userid` and `client-id` is used to form the url, if one of these parameters goes wrong, there will be 404 error because of the incorrect url. Content of parameter `roles` is warpped into post data, so if the format of `roles` parameter is wrong, there will probably be 500 error.

In order to get the right url example and the correct roles data structure, I used browser to manually assign a role, and check the url and post json data sent by the browser. Then change the code to produce the correct url and json data. Below is the final code that works:

```
from keycloak import KeycloakAdmin
# make connection        
admin = KeycloakAdmin(server_url = "https://xxx.xx.xx/auth/",
                      username = 'xx',
                      password = 'xxx',
                      realm_name = "xxx-xxx",
                      verify = True)
# get user id
userID = admin.get_user_id('one user's name')
# make sure you have the right realm name
realmName = 'xxx-xxx'
clientID = admin.get_client_id(realmName)
admin.assign_client_role(user_id = userID,
                         client_id = clientID, 
                         roles = [{"id":"34a02t60-2435-40da-v911-a3ee1xm58921",
                                   "name":"USER",
                                   "description":"xxxxx",
                                   "composite":False,
                                   "clientRole":True,
                                   "containerId":"aa102d71-4jk1-4u2a-a8w4-a6cv5j7626i1"}])
```